# Delete chunks of duplicate files in python from a very large file

Tags: python, file, duplicates, lines

My lab generates very large files relating to Mass spec data. With an updated program from the manufacturer some of the data writes out duplicated and looks like this:

```
BEGIN IONS
TITLE=IgA_OTHCD_uni.3.3.2
RTINSECONDS=0.6932462
PEPMASS=702.4431
CHARGE=19+
120.0028    2794.253
---lots more numbers of this format--
END IONS

BEGIN IONS
TITLE=IgA_OTHCD_uni.3.3.2
RTINSECONDS=0.6932462
PEPMASS=702.4431
CHARGE=19+
120.0028    2794.253
---lots more duplicate numbers---
END IONS
```

All chunks are of this format. I've tried writing a program to read in the whole file (1-2million lines), put the lines in a set and compare every new line to the set to see if it has been duplicated or not. The generated array of lines would then be printed to a new file. Duplicate chunks are supposed to be skipped over in the conditional statement but when I run the program it is never entered, instead printing out all received lines

```
print('Enter file name to be cleaned (including extension, must be in same folder)')
fileinput = raw_input()
print('Enter output file name including extension')
fileoutput = raw_input()

with open (fileoutput, 'w') as fo:
    with open(fileinput) as f:
        largearray=[]
        j=0
        linecount=0
    #read file over, append array
        for line in f:
            largearray.append(line)
            linecount+=1
        while j<linecount:
    #initialize set
            seen = set()
            if largearray[j] not in seen:
                seen.add(largearray[j])
    # if the first line of the next chunk is a duplicate:
            if 'BEGIN' in largearray[j] and largearray[j+5] in seen: 
                while 'END IONS' not in largearray[j]:
                    j+=1 #skip through all lines in the array until the next chunk is reached
            print('writing: ',largearray[j])
            fo.write(largearray[j])
            j+=1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

so just to clarify,

```
BEGIN IONS
TITLE=IgA_OTHCD_uni.3.3.2
RTINSECONDS=0.6932462
PEPMASS=702.4431
CHARGE=19+
```

this is repeated for the duplicated numbers etc right?

so you could just check to see if these initial parts are duplicated, and if so, skip till the next END IONS

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't skip over duplicates is the line:

```
seen = set()
```

It is in the wrong place.  If it is moved outside the loop, then the code will work as intended:

```
with open (fileoutput, 'w') as fo:
    with open(fileinput) as f:
        largearray=list(f)  #read file
        seen = set()  #initialize set before loop
        j=0
        while j<len(largearray):
            if largearray[j] not in seen:
                seen.add(largearray[j])
            # if the first line of the next chunk is a duplicate:
            if 'BEGIN' in largearray[j] and largearray[j+5] in seen:_
                while 'END IONS' not in largearray[j]:
                    j+=1 #skip through all lines in the array until the next chunk is reached
                j+=1  # Skip over `END IONS`
            else:
                print('writing: ',largearray[j])
                fo.write(largearray[j])
                j+=1
```

I made two other adjustments:

1. Looping over input lines of `f` to save them in a list is unnecessary.  This was replaced with:

   ```
   largearray=list(f)
   ```

   Ideally, to handle large files, we wouldn't read in the whole file at once but only one BEGIN/END block at a time. I will leave that as an exercise for the reader.
2. The code would print out `END IONS` even for duplicate section.  This was avoided by (a) incrementing `j` once more, and (b) using an `else` clause to print only the non-duplicate sections.

#### Alternative solution using `awk`

The same problem can be solved in `awk` in a single line:

```
awk -F'\n' -v RS="BEGIN IONS\n" '$5 in seen || NF==0 {next;} {seen[$5]++;print RS,$0}' infile >outfile
```

Explanation:

- `-F'\n' -v RS="BEGIN IONS\n"`

  `awk` reads in a record at a time.  Here, a record is defined as any text that begins with `BEGIN IONS` and a newline.  `awk` takes each record and divides it into fields.  Here we define the field separator as a newline character.  Each line becomes a field.
- `$5 in seen || NF==0 {next;}`

  If the fifth line in this record has already been seen, we skip over the rest of the commands and jump to the `next` record.  We do the same on any empty records that contain no lines.
- `seen[$5]++; print RS,$0`

  If we get to this command, that means that the record has not been seen before.  We add the fifth line to the array `seen` and print this record.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is huge, you should read it lines one-by-one and save only data you are interested for. So here's an iterate by line approach:

```
end_chunk           = 'END IONS'
already_read_chunks = set([])

with open(fileinput) as f_in:
    current_chunk   = []
    for line in f_in:                                       #read iterative, save only data you need
        line = line.strip()                                 #remove trailings and white spaces
        if line:                                            #skip empty lines
            current_chunk.append(line)
            if line == end_chunk:
                entire_chunk = '\n'.join(current_chunk)     #rebuild chunk as string
                if entire_chunk not in already_read_chunks: #check its existance
                    already_read_chunks.add(entire_chunk)   #add if we haven't read it before
                current_chunk = []                          #restore current_chunk var, to restart process

with open (fileoutput, 'w') as f_out:
    for chunk in already_read_chunks:
        f_out.write(chunk)
        f_out.write('\n')
        f_out.write('\n')
```